# How would I reset a .click toggle function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I'm making a infographic slider and I have buttons when clicked that reveal text. When I go to the next slider and then hit the previous button and go back my toggles reveal the text and then bounce back to be invisible.

Here is some of the code... I'm not sure if I should be resetting the css or Javascript div where each button is held? Please tell me how I can fix the toggle issue.

```js
$( "#point1" ).click(function() {
        $( "#timeline1" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });

      $( "#point2" ).click(function() {
        $( "#timeline2" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });

      $( "#point3" ).click(function() {
        $( "#timeline3" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });
    
      $( "#point4" ).click(function() {
        $( "#timeline4" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });

      $( "#point5" ).click(function() {
        $( "#timeline5" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });

      });
      
      / next and previous navigation functions
function showNextScreen() {
    
    // check if nav is active
    if (navActive) {
        
        // disable nav
        navActive = false;
        
        // targets the current screen
        currentScreen = "#screen" + screenNum;

        // sets next screen number
        screenNum++;

        // show/hide nav
        showHideNav(screenNum);

        // targets the next screen
        nextScreen = "#screen" + screenNum;

        // transitions current screen out
        gsap.fromTo(currentScreen, {
            x: 0
        }, {
            duration: duration,
            delay: 0.5,
            x: -960,
            ease: "power2.inOut"
        });

        // shows next screen
        $(nextScreen).show();

        // transitions next screen in
        gsap.fromTo(nextScreen, {
            x: 960
        }, {
            duration: duration,
            delay: 0.5,
            x: 0,
            ease: "power2.inOut",
            onComplete: function() {

                // hide current screen
                $(currentScreen).hide();
                
                // enable nav
                navActive = true;
            }
        });

        // load function to animate on contents of screen
        window["loadScreen" + screenNum]();

        // stop voiceover from playing
        $("#voiceover").trigger("pause");

    
        
    }
}

function showPrevScreen() {
    
    // check if nav is active
    if (navActive) {
        
        // disable nav
        navActive = false;
        
        // targets the current screen
        currentScreen = "#screen" + screenNum;

        // sets next screen number
        screenNum--;

        // show/hide nav
        showHideNav(screenNum);

        // targets the next screen
        prevScreen = "#screen" + screenNum;

        // transitions current screen out
        gsap.fromTo(currentScreen, {
            x: 0
        }, {
            duration: duration,
            delay: 0.5,
            x: 960,
            ease: "power4.inOut"
        });

        // shows previous screen
        $(prevScreen).show();

        // transitions next screen in
        gsap.fromTo(prevScreen, {
            x: -960
        }, {
            duration: duration,
            delay: 0.5,
            x: 0,
            ease: "power2.inOut",
            onComplete: function() {

                // hide current screen
                $(currentScreen).hide();

                // enable nav
                navActive = true;
            }
        });

        // load function to animate on contents of screen
        window["loadScreen" + screenNum]();

        
        
         // stop voiceover from playing
         $("#voiceover").trigger("pause");
        
    }
}

// next and previous button clicks
$("#next").click(showNextScreen);
$("#prev").click(showPrevScreen);
```

```css
#point1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 8%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/SVG/point1.svg" alt="fact" id="point1" class="point"/>
           <img src="img/SVG/point2.svg" alt="fact" id="point2" class="point"/>
           <img src="img/SVG/point3.svg" alt="fact" id="point3"class="point" />
           <img src="img/SVG/point4.svg" alt="fact" id="point4"class="point" />
           <img src="img/SVG/point5.svg" alt="fact" id="point5" class="point"/>
           
              <div id="prev">BACK</div>
        <div id="next">NEXT</div>
```

Comment: Do you want another timeline to disappear other than the one whose button was last pressed? Need more HTML to understand structure. You may also share your code using "outer snippet editor" resources such [link](https://jsfiddle.net/) if "local" does not have required lib to run snippet.

Comment: Kindly share the relevant html. I don't see any button in the one you've  provided.

Comment: @Vladimir if you visit my website you can see the project for better context .. its called interactive infographic. My website is hannahblue.ca

Comment: @ruleboy21  if you visit my website you can see the project for better context .. its called interactive infographic. My website is hannahblue.ca

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery's `.off()` method to remove the previous click event handler before adding `.click()` to the `#points`. Try this code

```
$( "#point1" ).off('click').click(function() {
    $( "#timeline1" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#point2" ).off('click').click(function() {
    $( "#timeline2" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#point3" ).off('click').click(function() {
    $( "#timeline3" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#point4" ).off('click').click(function() {
    $( "#timeline4" ).toggle("slow");
});

$( "#point5" ).off('click').click(function() {
    $( "#timeline5" ).toggle("slow");
});
```